# What is keyboard shortcut to cycle through worksheets in excel (office 2011) workbook on mackbook air?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ms-office

It looks like the shortcut is listed as Command+PageDown, but there's no "page down" on a mackbook air.  how can I cycle through the tabs (worksheets) in an excel workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's [Mac notebooks: Key placement and functions](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3164):

> <kbd>Page Up</kbd> key functionality is performed by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> key.
>
> <kbd>Page Down</kbd> key functionality is performed by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> key.

Comment: nailed it.  FN + command + up or down arrow cycles through the sheets.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this reference sheet may help:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/wsp_sample_file/excel_mac_shortcuts.pdf

Perhaps : fn-ctrl-up / fn-ctrl-down
Try this way: Ctrl+Page UP/Page Down to move Right/Left Tab

Answer (score 0):

option button and  up or down arrow

Comment: sorry the across buttons not up or down

Comment: There's an accepted answer for this question already that differs from your answer. Given this is likely wrong, you might want to consider deleting it as it will only attract downvotes. For more information on how Ask Different and the StackExchange Q&A format works please see our [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq).